# Django url mapping: regular expression

Tags: regex, django

In Django, I would like to use the regular expression:

```
url(r'^(?P<arg1>\w+)/(?P<arg2>\w*)/$', ...)
```

to match the following two requests:

```
http://localhost:8000/someApp/showData/
http://localhost:8000/someApp/showData/addRecord/
```

It doesn't work for the first request. How should I do it?

Comment: i think it won't work for the second one.

Comment: Actually, it works for the second one. The problem is that I don't know how to deal with the final slash if there is no arg2 (first request).

Comment: is this starts from someApp or showData?

Comment: start with showData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use two urlconf lines instead of one, one with one param and the other with both, both pointing to the same view which has the second argument optional. Something like:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns("",
    url(r"^(?P<arg1>\w+)/(?P<arg2>\w+)/$", yourview, name="yourview_with_arg1_arg2"),
    url(r"^(?P<arg1>\w+)/$", yourview, name="yourview_with_arg1"
)

# views.py
def yourview(arg1, arg2=None):
    pass # etc
```

This way your intentions are much clearer to anyone seeing your code later, and it's easier to extract some of the functionality into a separate view if necessary.

Comment: Good advise. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Add the preceding `/` before the second capturing group plus the second capturing group into a non-capturing group and make it as optional by adding `?` after the whole non-capturing group.

```
^(?P<arg1>\w+)(?:/(?P<arg2>\w*))?/$
```

OR

Make the preceding `/` character before the second non-capturing group as optional.

```
^(?P<arg1>\w+)/?(?P<arg2>\w*)/$
```